# ASP.NET hotmail-like address bar?

Tags: asp.net, hotmail

I have a form that a user enters a list of email addresses in a text box.
I want to give the text box the style of the hotmail adderess bar where each address is surrounded by a box.

is there any ideas about how to achieve this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hey guy maybe this link gives you the right direction:

http://devthought.com/blog/projects-news/2008/01/textboxlist-fancy-facebook-like-dynamic-inputs/

Basically you can achieve all of the functionality with ajax controls in asp.net